Error in the case where an XML starts with processing instruction
I use the redaction option in the mlcp export command
When the XML file starts with a PI in second line, I receive an ERROR :
[1.0-ml] RDT-NODE: (err:FOER0000) Unsupported node type: Only XML document or JSON document can redacted
The problem is in the redaction module, I test in XQuery (see bottom)
my file is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" href="../../../ml-schemas/coaching-report.form.sch"?>
<?xml-model type="application/xml" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" href="../../../ml-schemas/coaching-report.xsd"?>
<form version="coaching-report-v1" xmlns="http://data.eic.eu/model/coaching-report">
<entry name="managementTeam">
<question>
.......

if I delete the lines 2 and 3 :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form version="coaching-report-v1" xmlns="http://data.eic.eu/model/coaching-report">
<entry name="managementTeam">
<question>

I don't have any error.
My XQuery is :
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace rdt = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/redaction"
    at "/MarkLogic/redaction.xqy";

rdt:rule-validate("redactRules:anonymization"),
rdt:redact(doc('/data/template/coaching-report-v1.xml'), "redactRules:anonymization")


That seems like a bug to me. Processing Instructions are valid nodes for an XML document. I'll file a bug.
In the meantime, you can work around the problem by extracting the root element and constructing a new document to redact:
rdt:redact(document{doc('/data/template/coaching-report-v1.xml')/*}, "redactRules:anonymization")

and then if you need those PIs in the result, put them back into a redacted document:
let $doc := doc('/data/template/coaching-report-v1.xml')
let $redacted := rdt:redact(document{$doc/*}, "redactRules:anonymization")
return document{ $doc/processing-instruction(), $redacted/* }


I correct this bug directly in the Marklogic redaction.xqy file. file : Marklogic/Modules/Marklogic/redaction.xqy line 82 => [else if (not(xdmp:node-kind($doc/node()) =("element","processing-instruction","comment"))) ]

I have to modify the file \Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\Marklogic\redaction.xqy because I use redaction with mlcp
the line 82 :
from :
else if (xdmp:node-kind($doc/node()) ne "element")

to :
else if (not(xdmp:node-kind($doc/node()) =("element","processing-instruction","comment")))


the same problem exists for JSON who start by an array
